# Yii - Multiple relations to the same model

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, many-to-many

How can I in `YII` get the related model for each time it has been associated to a given model or at least get a count for how many times it has happened?

**The problem:**
I have a table of **Orders** and a table of **Products**.
*Each product is associated to the order 0 or more times*.

How do I through the standard relational tool in YII tell how many times a product is on an order?
I have created a many-to-many relationship through a joint-table and use it to declare my relations

```
'products'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Product', 'index_order_products(order_id, product_id)')
```

Problem is when I call *$order->products* it only returns the unique products, not a product for each time it is related.

I only need to know how many there are of each product on the order, so I've tried

```
'products'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Product', 'index_order_products(order_id, product_id)', 'select'=>'*, COUNT(product_id) as count', 'group'=>'product_id')
```

But if I then try calling `$order->products[0]->count` it says count hasn't been defined.
I've managed to circumvent this by creating a empty column count in the database. This way I get the number I need, but surely there must be a better way.

What would be the correct way of doing something like this in YII?

Comment: @afnan-bashir I thought about using a statistical query, but I can't figure out how or where to define it.
If I define it in `Orders` I will get a count of all products associated to the order, not for each individual product on the order.
And it doesn't seem to make sense to define it on `Products` since it only exists in the context of the order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well correct way would be using  [Statistical Query](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query) . It is for these purposes.

**The non elegant way**

> But if I then try calling $order->products[0]->count it says count
>   hasn't been defined.

this is because you are accessing count from object that is not returned when relation was evaluated.
Use `CVarDumper::Dump($order->products)` to see what you get in case of query

or the other way could be `count($order->products[0])`

Answer (score 0):

For use this you do need define `count` property in Product class

```
'products'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Product', 'index_order_products(order_id, product_id)', 'select'=>'*, COUNT(product_id) as count', 'group'=>'product_id')

 class Product extend CActiveRecord {
     public $count = 0;
 // skip in rules function add this
     array('count', 'safe'),
```